What model for my data?
I have a problem where we want to compare 3 treatments (a standard one against 2 new proposals). For each treatment we produce 5 objects. Each object is then divided in smaller parts and from each part we measure a given property.
I don't know if this is important but there is some spatial dependence in the parts from each object (in each object part 1 is contiguous with part 2, part 2 with 3 and so on).
So, I think I have the case of independent groups but with repeated measures within each group. As far as I looked in the literature, it seems that it directs me for a mixed ANOVA or hierarchical model? Could you give me some help on this and direct for some literature? I'm also doing this with R.
Thank you.
EDIT: the "objects" are in fact resulting from an industrial process (kind of a plastic); by "property" I mean mechanical properties of the object (I don't know details), measured as quantitative variables

What sort of measurement is done on these parts? It would also help to tell us what these things are, rather than general words like "property" and "object".  Yes, the geographic dependency will matter, you may need some kind of spatial model, but it's hard to tell without more detail.

A "quick and dirty" way of handling this would be to define a single aggregate measurement for each object, and then to run a standard one-way ANOVA on these, at least if there is no (spatial or other) dependence between objects. If possible it is probably better to also use a model "within object" as you apparently have in mind, but that may be complicated. Also an aggregate measurement may be helpful for simple and straight visualisation of the data, even if you end up using a more detailed model.

@PeterFlom I updated some more information on my post. I've also thought of making a mean of values, but they are also interested looking to that variation within the objects

This is a variant of a cluster randomized trial which can be analyzed with a multilevel model (a.k.a. mixed-effects model). You might also call it a nested design where the independent variable (the treatment) is administered at the whole object level, but your level of analysis is at a lower level, where observations are clustered in objects. If you added a second layer of treatment at the measurement level, you'd have a split-plot design. You can analyze this in R using one of several packages including lme4 or nlme
Here are some resources:
Multilevel modeling
Cluster randomized trials
nlme and lme4
